# collision two sprite dynamic and static and stop moving

Tags: phaser-framework, box2dweb

i have two sprite

```
var enemy1 = game.add.sprite(200 + 1*200,180,'enemy');
game.physics.box2d.enable(enemy1);
enemy1.body.static = true;

m_ship = game.add.sprite(150 + i * 125, 300, 'ship');
m_ship.scale.set(2);
m_ship.smoothed = false;
game.physics.box2d.enable(m_ship);
```

i use for collision  detect

```
m_ship.body.setBodyContactCallback(enemy1, enemyCallback, this);
```

i want when thy collision the  m_ship sprite stop moving 
thanks

Comment: What does `enemyCallback` currently have in it?

Comment: body2.sprite.destroy();
to destroy body2
i want stop body1 from moving
and put it in the samp possition of body2

Comment: What causes your ship to move? User input? Does it have velocity set by some other means?